# Checkbox [checked] = "true" not working in angular

Tags: angular

Trying to check the checkbox using [checked] = "true" but it is not working
here is a link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6qeay9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: If you use `[(ngModel)]`, **not** use  checked, just change the value of the variable: `theCheckbox=true` or `theCheckBox=false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see by the following [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-llleet?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<input type="checkbox"  [checked]="true"> List A
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox" [checked]="true"> List B
```

The `NgModel` directive is higher priority from the `checked` property.
So you may want to exclude `checked` and use `NgModel` to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

When the property is enclosed in brackets `[]`, the RHS is assumed to be a property in the controller (*.ts file). See [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#data-binding-and-html) for more info.

<s>In your case you must simply do</s>

```
checked=true
```

#### Update

I just saw the Stackblitz.

1. Since it's `<input>`, it must only be `checked`, not `checked=true`.
2. But you have a `ngModel` two-way binding. So you need to removed `checked` and set the status through the bound property `theCheckbox`.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  theCheckbox = true;
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-snyydi?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: let me check by updating it